# TargetDiskBlobAlreadyExists deploying vm template on Azure

Tags: templates, cloud, azure

I'm trying to deploy an ubuntu template on Azure. I have created the template from an existing machine with nothing installed. Here is the configuration:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "virtualMachines_StagingPortalWebServerNE_adminPassword": {
            "defaultValue": null,
            "type": "SecureString"
        },
        "virtualMachines_StagingPortalWebServerNE_name": {
            "defaultValue": "StagingPortalWebServerNE",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "networkInterfaces_stagingportalwebserv634_name": {
            "defaultValue": "stagingportalwebserv634",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "networkSecurityGroups_StagingPortalWebServerNE_name": {
            "defaultValue": "StagingPortalWebServerNE",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "publicIPAddresses_StagingPortalWebServerNE_name": {
            "defaultValue": "StagingPortalWebServerNE",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "virtualNetworks_StagingPortalWebServerNEResourceGroup_name": {
            "defaultValue": "StagingPortalWebServerNEResourceGroup",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "storageAccounts_stagingportalwebserv2173_name": {
            "defaultValue": "stagingportalwebserv2173",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/d897fa29-7454-411b-9709-d11a645bf42f/resourceGroups/StagingPortalWebServerNEResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/StagingPortalWebServerNE'.",
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "name": "[parameters('virtualMachines_StagingPortalWebServerNE_name')]",
            "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
            "location": "northeurope",
            "properties": {
                "hardwareProfile": {
                    "vmSize": "Standard_A1"
                },
                "storageProfile": {
                    "imageReference": {
                        "publisher": "Canonical",
                        "offer": "UbuntuServer",
                        "sku": "14.04.4-LTS",
                        "version": "latest"
                    },
                    "osDisk": {
                        "name": "[parameters('virtualMachines_StagingPortalWebServerNE_name')]",
                        "createOption": "FromImage",
                        "vhd": {
                            "uri": "[concat('https', '://', parameters('storageAccounts_stagingportalwebserv2173_name'), '.blob.core.windows.net', concat('/vhds/', parameters('virtualMachines_StagingPortalWebServerNE_name'),'201653123853.vhd'))]"
                        },
                        "caching": "ReadWrite"
                    },
                    "dataDisks": []
                },
                "osProfile": {
                    "computerName": "[parameters('virtualMachines_StagingPortalWebServerNE_name')]",
                    "adminUsername": "spotscale",
                    "linuxConfiguration": {
                        "disablePasswordAuthentication": true,
                        "ssh": {
                            "publicKeys": [
                                {
                                    "path": "/path/to/key",
                                    "keyData": "ssh-rsa sshkey"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "secrets": [],
                    "adminPassword": "[parameters('virtualMachines_StagingPortalWebServerNE_adminPassword')]"
                },
                "networkProfile": {
                    "networkInterfaces": [
                        {
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', parameters('networkInterfaces_stagingportalwebserv634_name'))]"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccounts_stagingportalwebserv2173_name'))]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', parameters('networkInterfaces_stagingportalwebserv634_name'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/d897fa29-7454-411b-9709-d11a645bf42f/resourceGroups/StagingPortalWebServerNEResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/stagingportalwebserv634'.",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
            "name": "[parameters('networkInterfaces_stagingportalwebserv634_name')]",
            "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
            "location": "northeurope",
            "properties": {
                "ipConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "name": "ipconfig1",
                        "properties": {
                            "privateIPAddress": "10.5.0.4",
                            "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                            "publicIPAddress": {
                                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', parameters('publicIPAddresses_StagingPortalWebServerNE_name'))]"
                            },
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworks_StagingPortalWebServerNEResourceGroup_name')), '/subnets/default')]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "dnsSettings": {
                    "dnsServers": []
                },
                "enableIPForwarding": false,
                "networkSecurityGroup": {
                    "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('networkSecurityGroups_StagingPortalWebServerNE_name'))]"
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', parameters('publicIPAddresses_StagingPortalWebServerNE_name'))]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworks_StagingPortalWebServerNEResourceGroup_name'))]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('networkSecurityGroups_StagingPortalWebServerNE_name'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/d897fa29-7454-411b-9709-d11a645bf42f/resourceGroups/StagingPortalWebServerNEResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/StagingPortalWebServerNE'.",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
            "name": "[parameters('networkSecurityGroups_StagingPortalWebServerNE_name')]",
            "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
            "location": "northeurope",
            "properties": {
                "securityRules": [
                    {
                        "name": "default-allow-ssh",
                        "properties": {
                            "protocol": "Tcp",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "22",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 1000,
                            "direction": "Inbound"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "allow-internet",
                        "properties": {
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "80",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "Internet",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 1010,
                            "direction": "Inbound"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "dependsOn": []
        },
        {
            "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/d897fa29-7454-411b-9709-d11a645bf42f/resourceGroups/StagingPortalWebServerNEResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/StagingPortalWebServerNE'.",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
            "name": "[parameters('publicIPAddresses_StagingPortalWebServerNE_name')]",
            "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
            "location": "northeurope",
            "properties": {
                "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
                "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 4
            },
            "dependsOn": []
        },
        {
            "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/d897fa29-7454-411b-9709-d11a645bf42f/resourceGroups/StagingPortalWebServerNEResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/StagingPortalWebServerNEResourceGroup'.",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
            "name": "[parameters('virtualNetworks_StagingPortalWebServerNEResourceGroup_name')]",
            "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
            "location": "northeurope",
            "properties": {
                "addressSpace": {
                    "addressPrefixes": [
                        "10.5.0.0/16"
                    ]
                },
                "subnets": [
                    {
                        "name": "default",
                        "properties": {
                            "addressPrefix": "10.5.0.0/24"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "dependsOn": []
        },
        {
            "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/d897fa29-7454-411b-9709-d11a645bf42f/resourceGroups/stagingportalwebserverneresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/stagingportalwebserv2173'.",
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "name": "[parameters('storageAccounts_stagingportalwebserv2173_name')]",
            "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
            "location": "northeurope",
            "tags": {},
            "properties": {
                "accountType": "Standard_LRS"
            },
            "dependsOn": []
        }
    ]
}
```

When I deploy the template I get the following error:

```
{
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "TargetDiskBlobAlreadyExists",
        "message": "Blob https://stagingportalwebserv2173.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/StagingPortalWebServerNE201653123853.vhd already exists. Please provide a different blob URI as target for disk 'StagingPortalWebServerNE'."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I understand that its a bad idea to use the same disk for two vms but I don't understand how to create a new one for this machine. Any help is appreciated.